# Create email link within a workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, email

I am creating a workflow in SharePoint 2013 that will email the user that created the list item. Within that workflow Define E-Mail Message box I would like to create a link to generate an email to the manager that is selected in the current item. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

'Workflow context' gives you 'Current Item URL'

[SharePoint Designer 2010 Workflow Email Link To Item](http://geekswithblogs.net/bjackett/archive/2011/02/18/sharepoint-designer-2010-email-link-to-item.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. But what I am referring to is a sort of mailto link. I have tried different versions and none appear to be working.

Comment: Could you update you post by adding the variants you have already tried? May be you had a minor error only

Comment: Manager is part of current item so you can get the email of the user assuming that 'Manager' is a person / group column. once you get the email id, you can add mailto tag to it!